# how to make the DropdownMenuEntries occupy the full width, flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a DropdownMenu and I have set that it occupies the full width of the screen, but their DropdownMenuEntries do not the same. I have tried with the ButtonStyle widget, but it does not work.

I attach a screenshot

[image]

I have pointed with a blue oval the unfilled space of the menu

**The code is**

```
class DropDownMenuCustom extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> items;
  final String? value;
  final String? hintText;
  final String? label;
  final void Function(String?)? onSelected;
  final TextEditingController? controller;

  const DropDownMenuCustom({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
    this.value,
    this.hintText,
    required this.label,
    this.onSelected,
    this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropDownMenuCustom> createState() => _DropDownMenuCustomState();
}

class _DropDownMenuCustomState extends State<DropDownMenuCustom> {
  late TextEditingController menuController;
  String? selectedValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    selectedValue = widget.value;
    menuController = TextEditingController(text: selectedValue);
    super.initState();
  }

  _handleOnSelected(String? newVal) {
    widget.onSelected!(newVal);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    menuController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    log(_width.toString());
    return DropdownMenu<String>(
      width: _width,
      controller: menuController,
      enableSearch: false,
      hintText: widget.hintText,
      menuStyle: MenuStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red)),
      dropdownMenuEntries: widget.items
          .map(
            (e) => DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
              value: e,
              label: e,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      inputDecorationTheme: _decoration(),
      onSelected: widget.onSelected != null ? _handleOnSelected : null,
    );
  }
}
```

**Information**:

- Flutter 3.7.0
- dart 2.19.0